# Google App Engine Dev Server Gives Error 500 (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea, localhost

I've just done a clean install of:

- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
- Google App Engine Java SDK 1.9.42
- Java JDK 1.8.0_102

I have just created a new Java Web Application in IntelliJ
That I will be running on my localhost (using the AppEngine Dev Server 1.9.42, this server is included in the App Engine SDK).

My project is brand new.

It auto-generated an index.jsp for me:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>$Title$</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      $END$
    </body>
  </html>
```

A default web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

And a standard appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <application></application>
  <version>1</version>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

I think that's all OK, but when I try to run this example. I get an ERROR 500...
(This looks like crap...I know)

> HTTP ERROR 500
>
> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> ```
> Unable to load class for JSP Caused by:
> ```
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: **Unable to load class for JSP**   at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:630)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:61)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:58)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:84)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:260)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:120)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
>     ... 65 more Caused by:
>
> **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp**    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:628)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.access$101(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:23)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet$2.run(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:61)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.PrivilegedJspServlet.service(PrivilegedJspServlet.java:58)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileUtils.serveWelcomeFileAsForward(StaticFileUtils.java:84)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.maybeServeWelcomeFile(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:260)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet.doGet(LocalResourceFileServlet.java:120)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:128)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at
>   com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:511)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)  at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)  at
>   org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>     at
>   org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

This is my project structure/layout:

[image: Project structure]

Does anybody with some more experience know what I could've done wrong?
If you need any further info, I'll happy to give it.

Thanks in Advance.

Tristan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App engine standard environment runs servlet spec 2.5 under Java 1.7

You'll need to change:

- web.xml to use the correct syntax for 2.5
- your jsp to use the correct syntax for jstl under 2.5 and
- make sure it runs under 1.7

I'd start with installing the 1.7 sdk then if everything is ok try putting it back to 1.8 sdk running for compatibility for 1.7 There are some versions of 1.8 that break jsp compilation when running under 1.7

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try

Comment: No luck,
Temporary swapped to tomcat, which is running fine.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Figured it out, Maven also had to use the 1.7jdk in my case